# Computed property "Parsing error: '}' expected at "

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, eslint

I am setting a computed property in my Vue component using typescript to define a return type and eslint is giving me an error. Any ideas on what is going on? The application runs as expected

I have attempted removing the typing or setting a `get()` associated however the problem persists no matter the formatting.

```
presets():Array<Iperf>{
    return this.$store.state.presets.iperf
}
```

The expected results should be no error, however the actual result is:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Parsing error: '}' expected at src\views\Iperf.view.vue:58:17:
  56 |     },
  57 |     computed: {
> 58 |         presets():Array<Iperf>{
     |                 ^
  59 |             return this.$store.state.presets.iperf
  60 |         }
  61 |     }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out that ESLINT was trying to parse my TypeScript as JSX. So I fixed some formatting.

Cannot use: `iperf:<Iperf>{}`

Use insetad: `iperf: {} as Iperf`